# Viewing raw XML from WCF Data Service in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF Data Service that exposes data from a database.  When I access this service in Internet Explorer, I get the raw XML as a response (after turning off feed reading view).  When I access this service in Firefox, Firefox shows it as an RSS feed.  When I access this service in Chrome, it prompts me to save the file.

1. Is there a way to disable feed reading view in Firefox as there is in Internet Explorer?
2. Can I set Chrome view the raw XML instead of trying to download it as a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears in newer versions of Chrome this is no longer an issue.  I have not tested Firefox recently.

Comment: Firefox v26 still has this issue.